# Accessing Cookies from a other Domain

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-hosting, google-cloud-run

I use Google Cloud Run and host a Server Side Rendered Website there (Nuxt).

Now for authentication I set a `access_token` Cookie on my Domain when a User logged in so I can access it on the Server to see if I can authenticate the User.

Now the problem is that my Firebase Hosting maps all incoming requests to the Google Cloud Run endpoint/domain.

When I set a Cookie on the Firebase Hosting it gets Set for the Domain the User is on (the firebase hosting domain), but when the request happens the Cloud Run Application checks for Cookies on the Cloud Run Endpoint/Domain, but wont find a suitable one because it sits on the Firebase Hosting Domain.

How can I tackle this issue?

Comment: You cannot share cookies across different domains. You can if they are a subdomain of a common root domain. Example sub1.example.com and sub2.example.com can share cookies. What are your domain mappings for each service? Hint: use domain mappings.

Comment: @JohnHanley There is no mapping, all requests to the Domain go to the Cloud Run Endpoint, I currently try to Map Cloud Run on my Domain directly without using Firebase Hosting, will see if that solves it or not

Comment: @JohnHanley seems like the mapping worked, would you mind explaining how mapping solves that or have any article? really curious. thanks

Comment: Just do a Google search on cookies. There are probably hundreds of articles.

Comment: Does your Cloud Run app not get cookies at all? Any language/framework should be able to parse all the cookies sent by the browser. Then you can roll with it. I agree with John, you should first learn how cookies work.